# Italic inline word with Interop.Word

Tags: c#, office-interop

I've starting learning C#, mostly for the purpose of MS Word automation. Using Interop.Word, how can I add a line with words "one two three" with two being italic? The closest I can get is something like this:

```
//text with some italic words.
para.Range.Text = "one ";
Console.WriteLine(para.Range.Start);
Console.WriteLine(para.Range.End);

// <some magic methods that end the last range and start a new one in place>

para.Range.Text = "two";
para.Range.Font.Italic = 1;
Console.WriteLine(para.Range.Start);
Console.WriteLine(para.Range.End);

// <some magic methods that end the last range and start a new one in place>

para.Range.Text = " three";
Console.WriteLine(para.Range.Start);
Console.WriteLine(para.Range.End);
para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

As for the method I need, I tried many things, but none of them worked. The MSDN documentation is very hard to read and omit many important details.

EDIT: I finally made it worked, by creating a new range object for every word. This is about as ugly as I could imagine but as least it works:

```
        Word.Range rng = word_doc.Range(para.Range.End - 1, para.Range.End);

        rng.Text = "one ";
        Console.WriteLine(rng.Start);
        Console.WriteLine(rng.End);

        rng = word_doc.Range(rng.End - 1, rng.End);
        rng.Text = "two";
        rng.Font.Italic = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(rng.Start);
        Console.WriteLine(rng.End);

        rng = word_doc.Range(rng.End - 1, rng.End);
        rng.Text = " three";
        rng.Font.Italic = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(rng.Start);
        Console.WriteLine(rng.End);
        para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Comment: Well, `para.Range.Font.Italic = 1;` should do it, but how can you tell it worked? Usign the `Console.WriteLine` will not show you the text as Italic... Are you aware of that?

Comment: It's unclear what is the problem. Your code seems fine except the `Console.WriteLine` parts which has nothing to do with `Word`.

Comment: Console.WriteLine is for simple logging; and the above code doesn't work as intended, only " three" is outputed. The "one " and "two" are overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I could get, the main issue with this code I made for you is that it doesn't add the text back inline, but instead adds a new line for each word it finds. Hopefully this code gives you some ideas on how to best programmatically create word documents!

```
Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);

Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;

Word.Paragraph para;
para = extendedDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
para.Range.SetRange(currentSelection.Range.Start, currentSelection.Range.End);

string string1 = "one two three";
string split1 = " ";
string match1 = "two";

string[] elements = Regex.Split(string1, split1);

foreach (var m in elements)
{
    if (m.Equals(match1))
    {
        para.Range.Text = m + " ";
        para.Range.Font.Italic = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        para.Range.Text = m + " ";
        para.Range.Font.Italic = 0;
    }

    para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
}
```

Edit: Have a good weekend! I will try to check my SO inbox over the weekend, but I may not reply to any questions till Monday.